# What is the Hulk's trigger?

Tags: marvel, the-incredible-hulk

As a general response to the Hulk, people say that it's just general (extreme) stress that brings out the Hulk.

However, over time Dr. Banner has come to control the Hulk. Eg. In "The Incredible Hulk" he claimed he "might be able to aim it", but by the end of the movie, was able to bring it out on command. This is the same in the Avengers.

From my (basic) understanding of the human psychology, a person cannot willingly bring himself under that much emotional stress at will.

So my question is: **What is the trigger for the Hulk, and how does Dr. Banner bring out the Hulk at will?**

Comment: Are you asking about the Hulk's portrayal in the Marvel Cinematic Universe specifically?  That would make this question easier to answer.

Comment: @user No, my question does extend to the comic universe as well. I have read a few issues where the Hulk has had "conscious" thoughts.

Comment: In "The Avengers" film - Banner reveals that the secret is "I'm always angry" - thus, it isn't a triggering of the Hulk so much as Banner actively repressing it. Only when he is mentally / physically compromised is it uncontrolled (ie - on the Helicarrier)

Comment: Banner has been in India studying mental control. I'm guessing he's learned to make himself angry/quell his anger as needed.

Comment: relevant: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/187446/58193

Comment: In the beginning of the comic I think he always changed at nightfall. This seems to be part of the newer series, The Immortal Hulk.

Answer (score 6):

Hulk's trigger is his heart rate, there are several indications of this:

- When the Bruce Banner is struggling to not become the Hulk in the factory in *The Incredible Hulk*, he keeps looking at his heart rate monitor
- When you are under emotional stress, your heart rate increases
- It is possible (people in the real world have done it) to control your heart rate to some degree with enough mental discipline
- It is plausible that the gamma radiation would trigger when enough energy is given to the body (which happens when your heart rate increases)

Answer (score 1):

In *The Incredible Hulk*, he becomes Hulk when his heart rate breaks 200 bpm. He also trains in yoga to control his stress, which eventually allows him to release The Hulk at will.

Comment: That's basically what my answer said...

Comment: @Anonymous I think the 200 is the main part

Comment: and his training with that guy (whats his name?)